# C. Can't open a text file with fopen on Windows Vista

Tags: c, fopen, windows-vista

I wanted to learn how to use `getc` function in C so I wrote a little program that is supposed to give the first letter of a text file as an output.
Here's how it looks:

```
int main()
{
    int character;
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    if(file == NULL)
        printf("can't open\n");
    character = getc(file);
    printf("%c", character);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

It fails to open the `file.txt` file and I can't figure out why. `file.txt` is in the same folder as my program's .exe file. I'm using Windows Vista.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're programming in an IDE like Visual Studio the programs current working directory when running is usually *not* the directory of the executable, but the project root directory.

Comment: Put the full path for the file into the `fopen`

Comment: I'm programming in Code Blocks

Comment: Same thing, most IDE usually uses the project root as the current working directory for the programs. Either move the file, or use a full and absolute path.

Comment: If you use `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` you can figure out the path from the executable's name at `argv[0]`.

Comment: I used the full path to my file, thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1):

This extracts the program's location from `argv[0]`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MYFILE "plik.txt"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char fname[_MAX_PATH+1];
    int znak;
    FILE *plik;
    char *ptr;
    strcpy(fname, argv[0]);
    ptr = strrchr(fname, '\\');
    if(ptr == NULL) {
        strcpy(fname, MYFILE);
    }
    else {
        strcpy(ptr+1, MYFILE);
    }
    plik = fopen(fname, "r");
    if(plik == NULL) {
        printf("Can't open %s\n", fname);
    }
    else {
        znak = getc(plik);
        printf("First char of %s is %c\n", fname, znak);
        fclose(plik);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if (plik == NULL) { perror("plik.txt"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

for a better understanding of the cause of error.